# Problem with detecting the value of the drop down list on the server (servlet) side

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, servlets

Client code is pretty simple:

```
<form action="DDServlet" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="customerText">
       <select id="customer">
             <option name="customerOption" value="3"> Tom </option>
             <option name="customerOption" value="2"> Harry </option>
       </select>
       <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Here is the code on the `Servlet`

```
Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()){
      String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();  //get the next element
      System.out.println(paramName);
}
```

When I print out, I only see, `customerText`, but not `customerOption`. Any idea why guys? What I hope is, if I select `Tom` in my option, once I submit, on my servlet I should able to do this: `String paramValues[] = request.getParameterValues(paramName);` and get back value of `3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `name` attribute on the select.  This should fix it up:

```
<select name="customerOption" id="customer">
    <option value="3"> Tom </option>
    <option value="2"> Harry </option>
</select>
```

Comment: +1, the parameter name will be customerOption, not customer.  I usually keep my id and name fields the same, but it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing, you did getParameterNames. Is that just example or is that the mistake?

Comment: `getParameterNames()` return `Enumeration`, which then u can iterate to all the elements in your form by `hasMoreElement()`. Make sure that your html tag contain `name` attributes.